# MessageBox in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a message box that will display 3 different Excel ranges.

This is my data:
[image: this is my data]

and I need to have a message box that should look like this:
[image: this is my data]

After clicking OK, it should display B1:B6 like this:
[image: this is my date]

And then when you click OK again it should display range C1:C6.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Message_Box()

Dim a As Range
Dim sTxt As String

For Each a In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a6")
sTxt = sTxt & vbLf & a.Value
Next a

MsgBox sTxt

End Sub
```

Comment: Currently, the code you have does column A correctly, yes? Why not just add two more loops?

Comment: would't it be better using a userform with 3 listbox ? Or just one listbox wit 3 columns ?

Comment: It's working fine now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub Message_Box()

Dim a As Range
Dim t As Integer
Dim sTxt As String

For t = 1 To 3
    For Each a In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, t), Cells(6, t))
    sTxt = sTxt & vbLf & a.Value
    Next a

    MsgBox sTxt
    sTxt = ""

Next t


End Sub
```

Comment: Haha, much more concise than where my brain went. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way you could do it:

```
Sub Message_Box2()
Dim a       As Range
Dim sTxt    As String
Dim myData() As Variant

Dim numCols As Long, numRows As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    numCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    numRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim myData(numCols, numRows)
    myData() = Range("A1:C" & numRows)
End With
Dim i As Long, k As Long, numTimes As Long
For k = 1 To numCols
    For i = 1 To numRows
        sTxt = sTxt & vbLf & myData(i, k)
        Debug.Print sTxt
    Next i
    MsgBox sTxt
    sTxt = ""
Next k
End Sub
```

Edit: It's a little overkill, but I was just wondering how one could use an array to do it, so made it before I realized it had already been answered.

Comment: @christinaG - Thanks! ...No need to change the answer to mine, if DarrelHarrie's works for you too. His is much more simple and straightforward (IMO), so you can mark his as the answer if you wish.